# how to select where like in ruby

Tags: sql, ruby

how to use like in query in ruby? im trying like this i my query is when starting words but i got error on like the variable tipo contains words like "DEV" or "QUA"

```
get_query("
       SELECT sid.sid 
       FROM sap_vm vm 
       INNER JOIN sap_instance instance 
            ON vm.id = instance.vm_id
       INNER JOIN sap_sid sid 
            ON sid.id = instance.sid_id
       WHERE sid.name LIKE '#{tipo}%'
        AND  vm.customer_id= '#{cliente_id}'").each do |item|
```

Comment: Please advise as to what is not working at the moment as well as what database you are using and what library or libraries you are using to connect to the database. I see nothing technically wrong with your query itself so it is difficult to tell what the actual question is here.

Comment: It is *extremely* concerning that you're using string interpolation here. You absolutely should be using **placeholder values**. Every Ruby SQL library I know of supports these out of the box.